# KeyboardInterrupt in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, keyboardinterrupt

How to generate a KeyboardInterrupt in Windows?

```
while True:
    try:
        print 'running'
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

I expected <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> to stop this program but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please, specify WHERE it doesn't work and how do you use it - otherwise we are unable to help you, we aren't clairvoyants... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working ok when ran into a windows console.

Ctrl+C generating a KeyboardInterrupt is a console feature. If you run it from a text editor like SciTE, it will not work.

Comment: That's right, it works fine when run from Vim (who starts a console) both on Linux and Windows. Thanks for the tip.